# How to GET row name NOT number of json and push it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

## I am using `GET` but its only giving me `row` numbers not `name` i think row names better than number << my Idea

So how to get `ID` row for `10` times and push into array but dont know how to do that when its giving me numbers of `JSON`.

My response  {0: "3", 1: "Bla", 2: "Title of Row"}

And if i Continue it with `NUMBERS` how to loop it 10 times like below example

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "Charts?q=news&order=id",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        for (var i in response) {
          var row = response[i];
          var id = response[0];
          var idO= [];
          idO.push(id);
        }
        console.log(idO);
    }
});
```

My Result is this now

```
Result:["1"];
```

How to `loop` it for `10 Times`

Comment: Are you saying you want just an array of the object values? `Object.values(response)` should give you `["3", "Bla", "Title of Row"]`

Comment: As far as why your snippet is only giving you one value, you're creating `idO` as a new array every iteration.  That should be done once outside the loop to avoid that

Comment: @Taplar i want to push 10 id of row and keep it in variable

Comment: What do you mean by "10 id of row"? There's only one object. Is it supposed to be an array of objects?

Comment: What is `NUMBERS`?

Comment: @Barmar my response is numbers My response {0: "3", 1: "Bla", 2: "Title of Row"} with 10 i meant 10 times loop

Comment: You need an array like `[{0: "3", 1: "Bla", 2: "Title of Row"}, {0: "5", 1: "Bla bla", 2: "Title of 2nd Row"}, ...]`

Comment: What sould var id be? Cannot find an id element in your response. You declare the id0 array in the for loop. That means, it‘ll be in each iteration an empty array again, until you push an element into it. The result will be an array with one entry.

Comment: that is actually my question too @MaximilianFixl what is standard way for that

Comment: @Barmar how then

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, because it‘s unclear what you mean with 10 times. Do you want to loop 10 times hardcoded over the response you‘ve got?

Comment: @MaximilianFixl yes loop (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialized the `idO` array before the loop, not each time. Then use a `for` loop that iterates 10 times.

There's no need for `for (i in result)` since you're not interested in processing each element of the object, you just want the ID in element `0`.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "Charts?q=news&order=id",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    var idO = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var id = response[i]["id"];
        idO.push(id);
      }
      console.log(idO);
  }
});
```

With the result you show, this should log

```js
["3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"]
```

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaanks !

Comment: @W1ZP3R I don't understand your edit. `response` is not an array, it's an object. There's no `id` property anywhere.

Comment: You also changed `response[0]` to `response[i]["id"]`. That's the part that doesn't match the response data in the question.